# Error while Installing Postgresql 11.5 to AIX 7.1

Tags: postgresql, aix

I am trying to install Postgres 11.5 on AIX 7.1 using  provided link:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/53E55FC8.4020304%40hogranch.com

When I tried to run

```
AR="/usr/bin/ar" ./configure --prefix=$HOME --64 --static
```

from inside `home/src/zlib-1.2.8` getting the following error

```
Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
./configure aborting.
```

Also I have gcc 4.8.0 on my AIX 7.1.

Anyone having idea to figure it out why I m getting this error.

**Content inside configure.log is below**

```
./configure --prefix=/ --64 --static
Checking for gcc...
=== ztest8323276.c ===
extern int getchar();
int hello() {return getchar();}
===
gcc -c ztest8323276.c
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
... using cc

Checking for obsessive-compulsive compiler options...
=== ztest8323276.c ===
int foo() { return 0; }
===
cc -c -O -qmaxmem=8192 ztest8323276.c
./configure[3]: cc:  not found
(exit code 127)
Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
** ./configure aborting.
```

Comment: Find the entries in `config.log` that belong to the error and add them to the question.

Comment: Nono, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58390093/edit) and add the information there.

Comment: You seem _not_ to have gcc properly installed.

Comment: Lorinczy Zsigmond -  gcc is installed on my machine which  I have verified running command "which gcc" which  shows me gcc (GCC) 4.8.3.

Comment: Below is the command which breaks 
    AR="/usr/bin/ar" ./configure   --prefix=$HOME --64 --static.

I have read to pass LDFLAGS="-Wl,-bbigtoc"
How to pass LDFLAGS="-Wl,-bbigtoc"  or need to update configure file?
For a 64-bit build, set OBJECT_MODE to 64 and pass CC="gcc -maix64" and
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-bbigtoc" to "configure". (Options for "xlc" might differ.)
If you omit the export of OBJECT_MODE, your build may fail with linker
errors. When OBJECT_MODE is set, it tells AIX's build utilities such as
"ar", "as", and "ld" what type of objects to default to handling.